# Are there any good 2D UITableView like implementations out there?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, 2d

So what I'm looking for is a table view that supports and displays an array of cells (think excel).

The 2D implementation should have cell caching for performance, optimized for panning.

Comment: As a note, I ended up using CATiledLayer.  It provides low-level drawing on a background thread to keep the UI thread smooth.